# How to capture the mouse drag coordinates using JavaScript in JSP page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have to capture the `start (x,y)` coordinate and `end (x,y)` coordinate of a mouse event. Example: I have an image in HTML page, what is going to be happen is like, user can able to select any particular area with the help of mouse drag.

So I want to capture the coordinates from where it start and where it ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = [];
var end = [];
myImage.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
    var e = e || event;
    start = [e.x || e.clientX,e.y || e.clientY];
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
    var e = e || event;
    end = [e.x || e.clientX,e.y || e.clientY];
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark,

one more thing I want to ask, is it possible to select particular area of an image with mouse event like what we can do in microsoft paint using javaascript or jquery.

Regards,
Vidya Bhushan

Comment: Hmm, more or less. You can store these positions (start and end). But if you want to crop this image using these positions, you have to use the HTML5 Canvas tag [Crop Image](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/)